# Web media streaming with IIS 6.0 and IE 11 (Win 7 client)

Tags: internet-explorer, silverlight, iis, video-streaming

Is there any chance to create a simple streaming video web page using IIS 6.0 as a backend and Windows 7 with IE 11 as a client? I need to embedd the web page within a WPF app.

I have tried DASH JS player, but it seems not to support IE 11 on Windows 7 and also it did not work for me on the server part (not sure why). I can also use flash or silverlight but I would like a freeware opensource solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this open source silverlight project right when I was writing this question:

[Silverlight Video Player](https://slvideoplayer.codeplex.com/)

First I had to convert FLV video to MP4 (used Convertzilla app to do this).
Then I had to enable MIME types within IIS 6.0 (Web site properties - HTTP Headers - MIME Types):

```
.xap = application/x-silverlight-app
.xaml = application/xaml+xml
.xbap = application/x-ms-xbap
.mp4 = video/mp4
```

Created the `ClientBin` folder within the website root directory on the server and copied my video `20151018.mp4` there as well as `VideoPlayerThemed.xap` and `VideoPlayer.xap` files from the mentioned CodePlex project.

Then I have embedded my video in the HTML web page:

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="1024" height="850">
    <param name="source" value="ClientBin/VideoPlayer.xap"/>
    <param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
    <param name="background" value="gray" />            
    <param name="initParams" value="autostart=true,cc=false,markers=false,m=20151018.mp4" />
    <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=115261" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Pro zobrazení videa si stáhněte Silverlight" style="border-style: none"/>
    </a>
</object>
```

And it just worked, so I did not spend days on the task.